# How do I use the where-object cmdlet to find text that -contains a certain word

Tags: windows, powershell, csv

I'm setting up a contacts file in .csv format, as downloaded from google, to read with powershell on my windows 10 laptop. I have a long way to go to make this practical, but the first thing I've tried, and almost succeeded in, is to write a script that prompts the user to enter a name and then responds with the phone number for them. That script looks like this:

```
 Param(
     [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0, HelpMessage="What's their name?")]
     $TheirNameIs
  )
 Import-Csv "*MYPATH*.csv" |

     Sort 'Family name' -descending |

     Where-object {$_.Name -eq $TheirNameIs} |

     Select-Object -Property 'Name','Phone 1 - Type','Phone 1 - Value'
```

The problem I am having is Where-object works with -eq to find exact matches to the name the user enters, but I wanted to use -contains so that I could type in a first name and get all the contacts with that value in their name. I tried replacing -eq with -contains but wasn't getting any output unless I used the exact contact name

Where am I going wrong with the Where-object cmdlet?

Comment: Try to replace `-eq` with `-match`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could replace the `-eq` operator by the `-like` operator and insert wildcards:

```
Param(
     [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0, HelpMessage="What's their name?")]
     $TheirNameIs
)
Import-Csv "*MYPATH*.csv" |
Sort 'Family name' -descending |
Where-object {$_.Name -like "*$TheirNameIs*"} |
Select-Object -Property 'Name','Phone 1 - Type','Phone 1 - Value'
```

You could also go for regular expressions and use the `-match` operator like @Olaf already mentioned. A solution could look like this:

```
Param(
     [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0, HelpMessage="What's their name?")]
     $TheirNameIs
)
Import-Csv "*MYPATH*.csv" |
Sort 'Family name' -descending |
Where-object {$_.Name -match ".*$TheirNameIs.*"} |
Select-Object -Property 'Name','Phone 1 - Type','Phone 1 - Value'
```